# No HTML output for SQL queries with more than one column in a FOR loop

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, powershell-2.0

I'm processing different SQL queries in a `for` loop to export them to a HTML report.

This is my code:

```psh
$OutputFile = "MyReport.htm"

##set HTML formatting
$a =  @"
<style>
BODY{background-color:white;}
TABLE{border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: auto
}
TH{border-width: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color:#C0C0C0
}
TD{border-width: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color:white
}
</style>
"@

$a | ConvertTo-Html -head $a | Out-File $OutputFile

for ($i=0; $i -lt $dataSource.Length; $i++) {
  $TableHeaderActual = $TableHeader[$i]

  $body = @"
<p style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;family:helvetica;color:black;">
$TableHeaderActual
</p>
"@

  $dataSourceActual = $dataSource[$i]
  $databaseActual = $database[$i]
  $sqlCommandActual = $sqlCommand[$i]

  ##Create a string variable with all our connection details 
  $connectionDetails = "Provider=sqloledb; " +
                       "Data Source=$dataSourceActual; " +
                       "Initial Catalog=$databaseActual; " +
                       "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

  ##Connect to the data source using the connection details and T-SQL command we provided above, and open the connection
  $connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $connectionDetails
  $command = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand $sqlCommandActual,$connection
  $connection.Open()

  ##Get the results of our command into a DataSet object, and close the connection
  $dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $command
  $dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
  $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
  $connection.Close()

  [string]$props = $dataSet.Tables[0] |
     Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, ItemArray, HasErrors, Table -First 1 |
     ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -Expand Name }

  ##Return all of the rows and pipe it into the ConvertTo-HTML cmdlet, and then pipe that into our output file
  $dataSet.Tables[0] |
    ConvertTo-Html -Body $body -Property $props |
    Out-File -Append $OutputFile
}
```

`$TableHeader`, `$dataSource`, `$database` and `$sqlCommand` are arrays of strings.

It works, but when I get the result of a SQL query with more than one column the output doesn't work. All I get, is the table border and that's it.

Can you help?

Comment: Please, specify which SQL server you are using (MySQL, MS SQL). This will increase the chance of a good answer for you.

Comment: Why are you still casting `$props` to string? DON'T DO THAT.

Comment: @Alan: Forgot that, sorry - MSSQL

Comment: @Ansgar: Otherwise it won't work...

Comment: I just tested it and it works just fine. If it doesn't work for you: please provide evidence. Show the output of `$props | % { "-$_- [$($_.GetType().FullName)]" }` and `$dataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Html -Property $props`. Also, what PowerShell version do you have (`$PSVersionTable`)?

Comment: `$props | % { "-$_- [$($_.GetType().FullName)]" }` is `[System.String]`. Errormessage is the following `ConvertTo-Html : System.Management.Automation.PSObject kann nicht in einen der folgenden Typen konvertiert werden: {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}`

Comment: PowerShell version is 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation (or a bug) of the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet in PowerShell v2. According to the online help the parameter should accept an object array as input:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.3655
BuildVersion                   6.0.6002.18111
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1

PS C:\> Get-Help ConvertTo-Html -Parameter Property

-Property <Object[]>
    Includes the specified properties of the objects in the HTML.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    1
    Default value
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

However, in PowerShell v2 it only works if you cast the list of property names to a string array:

```psh
[string[]]$props = $dataSet.Tables[0] |
    Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, ItemArray,
        HasErrors, Table -First 1 |
    ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -Expand Name }
```

Casting to a string array works regardless of whether you have one or more property names.

A better solution, however, would be to upgrade to at least PowerShell v3, to actually fix the problem.

Comment: Now it works! All errors are gone and all results are shown correct. Thank you very much! In the next step I will upgrade to the newest version of PowerShell.